# How to improve my aural?

Tags: piano, abrsm

This year, I'm taking the ABRSM piano test, Grade 5. Every year, I ALWAYS seem to have trouble with the aural. Everything else is fine, but it's always the aural part that lowers my grade.

Is there a way where I can improve my aural? I've tried numerous things, like playing random keys on the piano and singing them back, singing parts of my piano songs, even using the ABRSM practice aural tests, but nothing seems to help. Any suggestions?

Comment: A lot of musical activities help your aural training. A particularly good one is singing in a choir. If you are able to join one, go for it. The amount you learn from sight-singing, and relating notes in a score to the notes you sing, is really useful.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as it's a duplicate of a question I answered awhile ago. "How to practice Audition"

Comment: At that level, you probably have a teacher. If not, well done! That teacher should be spending a proportion of a lesson on aural training - I put it in integrally - 'sing that phrase you just played, sing the second and third note of the scale that starts on Eb, etc. As aural is 10% of the marks, ( I think), 10% of a lesson could be spent on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it will help if you grab a stringed instrument and play with the tuning pegs for a few afternoons in the week.  Reason being is that the piano is really like a big harp with tiny mallets attached to keys.

There is a layer there that makes it a mystery, but if you break through to what's going on physically with the strings it will probably make it easier to "hear."